# Shifted text in swing app on OS X

Tags: java, swing, text, shift

I have a little java+swing app. Until now it worked OK, on OS X and on windows.

But recenly a user has noticed that on his OS X (version unknown yet, nor the java version) that all texts in the GUI are shifted up and cut (as you can see on the screenshot).

[wrong look http://b3.s3.quickshareit.com/picture1ac6aa.png](http://b3.s3.quickshareit.com/picture1ac6aa.png)

And HTML link is shifted down and cut. All those elements are JLabels.

This is how it should look like

[ok look http://b1.s3.quickshareit.com/screenshot_45f5e29f947e59b81.png](http://b1.s3.quickshareit.com/screenshot_45f5e29f947e59b81.png)

Any ideas/help? Has anybody had this problem before? I have no clue where to start. Thanks for any help

I googled "java jlabel crop/cut" etc.

==========

fragment of the code

```
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import System.DnDList;
import System.QSTWindow;
import System.configuration.Configuration;


public class Test extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8698865819017225558L;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test main = new Test();
        main.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel down_panel;
    private JButton b_Preferences;
    private JButton b_AddFile;
    private JButton b_Send2;
    private JButton b_Cancel;
    private JButton b_Cancel2;
    private DnDList dndList;
    private JLabel filesToSendLabel;
    private JLabel browseFilesLabel;
    private JPanel selectedFilesPanel;
    private JPanel gPanel;    

    public Test()
    {
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255)); // XXX move color to configuration class
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setSize(360, 525); // whole window

        gPanel = new JPanel();
        gPanel.setLayout(null);
        gPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        gPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 365, 525); // whole window panel


        selectedFilesPanel = new JPanel();
        selectedFilesPanel.setLayout(null);
        selectedFilesPanel.setBounds(0, 333, 440, 122);
        selectedFilesPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        down_panel = new JPanel(); // panel with info button and upload button
        down_panel.setLayout(null);
        down_panel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        down_panel.setBounds(0, 430, 365, 80);

        // icon taken from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Image:Information_icon.svg
        b_Preferences = new JButton("PREF");
        b_Preferences.setFocusPainted(false);
        b_Preferences.setToolTipText("Settings");
        b_Preferences.setBackground(Configuration.getBACKGROUND_COLOR());
        b_Preferences.setBounds(11, 25, 32, 32);
        b_Preferences.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        b_Preferences.setBorderPainted(false);

        b_AddFile = new JButton("Browse");
        b_Send2 = new JButton(new ImageIcon(QSTWindow.class.getResource("upload.png")));
        b_Cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        b_Cancel2 = new JButton("Cancel");

        dndList = new DnDList(selectedFilesPanel, 8, 10, 364, 97, this);

        filesToSendLabel = new JLabel("Media to send");
        filesToSendLabel.setFont(Configuration.getDEFAULT_LABEL_FONT());
        filesToSendLabel.setBounds(10, 325, 150, 14);
        browseFilesLabel = new JLabel("<HTML><U>Browse</U></HTML>");
        browseFilesLabel.setForeground(Configuration.getLINK_COLOR());
        browseFilesLabel.setFont(Configuration.getLINK_FONT());
        browseFilesLabel.setBounds(90, 325, 50, 14);

        b_Send2.setBounds(272, 25, 72, 26);
        b_Send2.setMargin(new Insets(3, 0, 3, 0));

        down_panel.add(b_Preferences);
        down_panel.add(b_Send2);

        gPanel.add(filesToSendLabel);
        gPanel.add(browseFilesLabel);
        gPanel.add(selectedFilesPanel);
        gPanel.add(down_panel);

        this.add(gPanel);
        this.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

Sorry that this example is not compillable (you'd need half of the app), but shows the problematic elements.

Comment: Can you post some code? In particular the code for building the UI

Comment: Added source code for the main frame

Comment: Is this solved by now?
Can you provide code to reproduce the bug? I've got a rather old mac (OS X 10.4 with java 1.5.0_19), but I cannot compile the sample code because I lack some referred classes.

Comment: Not solved yet. I'll try to prepare some working code BUT i DO NOT guarantee that it will have the issue included - it works on 10.5 and I cannot tell whether it will NOT work on 10.4 :/

Comment: OK, leave this problem.
Preparing working example is too time consuming. It seems it requires lots of classes from the project.
And other hand, I cannot give you full buildable project.

I'll try to get Tiger OS / Machine.

Thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking that maybe the problem has something to do with the Fonts installed in the system.

Can you set the text to some known Font that you're 100% sure it's going to be installed in the system?

Comment: Thank's for the tip
I use Arials: regular and bold - they rather are available everywhere